# Comma in infinitive construction

Tags: grammar, comma, infinitive

In "Lehr- und Übungsbuch der deutschen Grammatik", I found some sentences:

> Ich fürchte, dass ich bald entlassen werde.
>   Ich fürchte, bald entlassen zu werden.
>   Sie hofft, dass sie vom Bahnhof abgeholt wird.
>   Sie hofft vom Bahnhof abgeholt zu werden.
>
> Anmerkung:
>   Das Komma vor der Infinitivkonstruktion ist nach der Rechtschreibreform nicht mehr obligatorisch, es kann aber [...] stehenbleiben.
>   [...]
>   Es muss stehenbleiben, wenn die Infinitivkonstruktion [...] im übergeordneten Satz durch ein Bezugswort angekündigt ist.

I would like to know

- do you think a "can-rule" is ever a good idea?
  (I know this question is a little bit general, but I would like to know your opinions.)
- would it be correct to write

> Ich fürchte dass ich bald entlassen werde.

- can you give me an example for the last sentence of the comment? ("Es muss stehenbleiben, ...")

Comment: If I recall correctly, there should always be a comma before "dass."

Comment: @Kevin: Unless it is "so dass" (though Duden for some reason prefers "sodass" anyway) ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Yes, it is a good idea to have a "can-rule". First, people who are used to the old rule make fewer mistakes, second, you can structure your sentence with the additional comma and third, most important, you can avoid misunderstandings with this rule:

> Wir empfehlen ihm zu folgen.

This could mean:

> Wir empfehlen, ihm zu folgen.

or

> Wir empfehlen ihm, zu folgen.

2) There is always a comma before "dass", so no, it is not correct.

3) If you use „als", „anstatt", „außer", „ohne", „statt" or „um", you have to set a comma.

See this [grammar rule](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K117), scroll to "Regel 116" and "Regel 117".

Comment: Good point. This makes sense.

Comment: In 1) you point out the advantages of allowing the comma to be there. But what is the advantage of allowing it to be omitted?

Comment: @AndreKR: Follow my link. For "simple" sentences like "Wir zweifeln nicht daran zu gewinnen" it does not make a difference if there is a comma or not. I would put a comma there, because I'm used to do it. But many people think it's superfluous there.

Comment: There is no “can-rule” in the _Neue Rechtschreibung_. “Wir empfehlen, ihm zu folgen.” is wrong. Please see [this excellent tutorial](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/komma-setzung-regeln.php) (which also explains why the Duden is wrong about there being 32 rules: there is only one).

Comment: Well, @Clemens, I disagree. See section E:2,c) in http://pub.ids-mannheim.de/laufend/sprachreport/pdf/sr11-extra.pdf

Comment: I know that section. It is discussed on the page I linked in detail (and quite convincing I might add)!

Comment: No, it's not convincing, @Clemens, especially because this section says, that there is a can-rule. But it's not the first time I disagree with belleslettres.

Comment: I acknowledge of course that there is a can-rule for the cases mentioned in the section or if otherwise the sentence would be ambiguous (1). In all other cases I don't think one has a choice.    (1) Which prooves me wrong, though, regarding “Wir empfehlen, ihm zu folgen.” ...