# Mit oder ohne Komma: "Ich denke dies in Ihrem Unternehmen zu finden."

Tags: punctuation, comma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma in infinitive construction](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/comma-in-infinitive-construction)

Ich bin mir unsicher, ob es ein Komma braucht:

> "Ich denke, dies in Ihrem Unternehmen zu finden."

Comment: Ja, Komma notwendig.

Comment: Only after posting my answer I found this possible duplicate: [Comma in infinitive construction](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3124).

Comment: Nach der neuen Rechtschreibung darf hier kein Komma gesetzt werden. [Ich empfehle dieses exzellente Tutorial zur Kommasetzung](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/komma-setzung-regeln.php)

Comment: Schwer zu sagen, da der Satz keinen Sinn ergibt.

Answer (score 5):

Nach alter Rechtschreibung war ein Komma *notwendig* („erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu“)

Nach neuer Rechtschreibung *braucht* man *kein* Komma zu setzen. Ich würde es aber trotzdem empfehlen, „um die Gliederung des Satzes deutlich zu machen“. Die Details finden sich in den [Regeln 116 und 117 im Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K116).